# fstring float to int with leading zeros

Tags: python, f-string

I need to generate a string from a float which is always the length of 5.
For example:

```py
input_number: float = 2.22
output_str = "00222"
```

The float never larger then 999.xx and can have an arbitrary number of decimal places.
I came up with the following code, but I doubt whether what I have in mind can't be done in a more pythonic way.

My solution:

```py
input_number = 343.2423423
input_rounded = round(input_number, 2)
input_str = str(input_rounded)
input_str = input_str.replace(".","")
input_int = int(input_str)
output_str = f"{input_int:05d}"
```

More examples:

343.2423423 -> "34324" 
23.3434343 -> "02334"

Comment: So you always want the three digits before the decimal, even if there are leading zeroes?

Comment: yes exactly. So 0.34 -> 00034. I need to address an old dependency that for whatever reason needs a filename in this exact format.

Comment: What you have is pretty fine. The int stage is not necessary. i.e. you can go directly from `input_str` (after the `replace`) to [`output_str = input_str.zfill(5)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill)

Comment: Using floats (coded in a certain way) as parts of file names seems like a dubious idea. Round-off error could render a file inaccessible.

Comment: @JohnColeman yes I know. Feel free to convince my boss that this needs to be changed :D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this match your use cases:

```
for input_number in (343.2423423, 23.3434343, 0.34, .1):
    num, decimal = str(input_number).split('.')
    print(f"{num.zfill(3)}{decimal[:2].ljust(2, '0')}")
```

Out:

```
34324
02334
00034
00010
```

Comment: @sebwr: Edited to match all cases I can think of

Comment: Be aware that in case you might ever pass this an integer, it will break. Can be fixed by converting to a float, though.

Comment: Yes, although OP explicitly mentioned `float`.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Good point. I will annotate it with a type hint. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest way I can think of. Format it into a string with two decimal places shown and six total characters (left-filling with zeroes), then remove the decimal point.

```
def format_number(number):
    return f'{number:06.2f}'.replace('.', '')
```

The [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) can seem pretty arcane, but in this case it's just:

- `0`: the character to fill with
- `6`: the total number of characters to produce (including the decimal)
- `.2`: the number of digits to show after the decimal
- `f`: fixed-point float notation

Comment: This looks really nice. I will test it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
for input_number in (343.2423423, 23.3434343, 0.34, .1, 23.45, 2.32):
    num, decimal = str(input_number).split('.')
    formatted_num = "{:03d}".format(int(num))
    formatted_decimal = "{:.2f}".format(float("0."+decimal))[2:]
    print(formatted_num+formatted_decimal)
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why (something about floating point math, I'm sure), but using this for `23.45` gives me `02344`. Other methods shown behave as expected, and this one works fine for other numbers I've tried. (Not that floats should ever really be trusted for specific digits like this anyway.)

Comment: `2.32` becomes `00231`....